# SpringMVC Validation Issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, validation

I am having some problems in the Controller Class. I have a Login page the first time it is called the Controller uses the method annotated with the GET request. When the form is posted it will then use the method annotated with the POST request.

Only when the form is posted i want to execute validation. So validation check is placed in the POST method (@Valid). I have an @InitBinder function but this does not get executed when i POST the form so no error messages are returned from the Validation class nor is the 'result.hasErrors()' method getting set to false. If i place @Valid on the GET i get validation happening meaning result.hasErrors() gets set to false.

I am not sure when the @InitBinder function gets executed or how to only allow execution at the request of a POST. Presently the only message that gets executed when the page is GET is 'Welcome it was a get' which is what i want, but the POST i am getting 'Error!!! It was a post' and validation does not get executed. Under is some code:

Code in the Controller Class

```
@InitBinder("login")
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
    binder.setValidator(new LoginValidation());

}
```

---

I am not doing anything in the GET besides displaying the page

```
@RequestMapping(value="login.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,Model model, @ModelAttribute("login") Login login,BindingResult result )
            throws ServletException {

            return new ModelAndView("login","errorMsg", "Welcome it was a get");             


}
```

---

```
@RequestMapping(value="login.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, @Valid @ModelAttribute Login login, BindingResult result, ModelMap m) throws Exception {



         if(result.hasErrors()){


             return new ModelAndView("login", "errorMsg", "Errors was detected");

        }else{

            if (authenticationManager.Authenticate(login) == true){

                return new ModelAndView("main","welcomeMessage", message);
            }           

            return new ModelAndView("login","errorMsg", "Error!!! It was a post");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There were white spaces in my parameters. Using binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true)) in the @InitBinder("login") solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

The first time the page is requested using a GET the validation works, this happens mainly because the fields are blank upon request of the page and the @InitBinder("login") will execute before anything happens on the page every time its requested.

The reason the validation did not fail when the page was POST even though the fields in the view were left blank was mainly due to white spaces since the validation ran on the page GET request and returned the object back to the view with white spaces during data binding.

To remedy this problem i did a count of the length of the fields in the validation logic and logged it to the server.When the logs were investigated i saw the fields were not NULLS since the validation logic was checking mainly for NULLS.

Solution for white spaces :In the @Controller @InitBinder function include:

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
```

This will trim away the white spaces